# What fingerprint formats are returned by WinBioCaptureSample?

Tags: c#, .net, fingerprint

I've got a C# application running on Win7 and a USB fingerprint scanner. I'm talking to the scanner via Windows Biometric Framework (WBF). `WinBioCaptureSample()` gets me something, a lot when I ask for `_RAW`, a little when I ask for `_PROCESSED`.

I assume that "raw" is an image and that "processed" is a template, but what formats are they using??

I need the sample as either an image (any standard format) or an INCITS-378 template, and Microsoft's docs don't say if that's possible. I can't even figure out how to use the offsets in the `WINBIO_BIR_DATA` structure to find the data in memory.

I note again that this is C#, not C++.

Any clues?

**Edit** I'll settle for *any* sample code that calls `WinBioCaptureSample()` (other than what's on MSDN).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from MSDN:
**The BIR is compatible with the Common Biometric Exchange Format Framework (CBEFF) defined by NIST 6529-A.**

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd401648%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[NIST 6529-A](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistir/NISTIR6529A.pdf)

[This Presentation](http://www.w3.org/2008/08/siv/Slides/Daon/BioAPI-Tilton-2009-full.pdf) has a great description of the BIR format byte by byte..

Comment: +1, because although I can't verify whether your answer is sufficient (and it doesn't point to a sample), it might have been enough at the time.